# MMU and Page Table

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory, mmu, page-tables

Page table is a data structure created by the programmer. So how does the MMU know how to access the page table? I know the MMU gets the address of the page table from the page table base register but how does it reads the page table afterwards? The MMU doesn't know the data structure of the page table created by the programmer.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**No**! PageTable DataStructure is designed by **System Architecture Designers**, And also they have designed MMU; So, MMU is perfectly aware of the structure of PageTable.
**Operating System Developer** do not choose any arbitary format for PageTable datastructure; they follow the machine's architecture manual.

Answer (score 1):

As you state, the page table is defined by hardware registers.

Operating system is is responsible for ensuring that the the structure of the page table conforms to that which the MMU will recognize.

> The MMU doesn't know the data structure of the page table created by the programmer.

The MMU knows A data structure. IF the page table conforms to the structure known by the MMU all is goodness. If the programmer creates some arbitrary structure that does not conform to the one the MMU expects, the system will crash.

For example of such a structure, see p. 203 onward from here

http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/dec/vax/archSpec/EY-3459E-DP_VAX_Architecture_Reference_Manual_1987.pdf

Comment: For your first line, isn't that he state the opposite?